# maven multi-module project with two versions of protobuf

Tags: java, maven, language-agnostic, protocol-buffers, dependency-management

We have a multi-module maven project.  One of the modules has a bunch of `.proto` files, which we compile to java files.  Pretty much every other module depends on this module.  Most of them use Protobuf 2.4, but one needs to use 2.5.

Is there any nice way to do this?  (The not nice way is to edit the pom file to say "2.5", build a jar, manually copy that jar to wherever we need it, and then change the pom file back to 2.4.)

Comment: Download libprotobuf 3, which supports both "proto3" and "proto2" syntax. Rebuild your code from source, and you'll unify all your protos so you don't need any manual tricks in order to make it compile.

Comment: no they're both proto2; I'm not using proto3 at all

Comment: What I'm currently leaning towards is "duplicating" the module with all the protos, but instead of copying the protos, I'll have to new pom refer to the protos of its twin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never used protobuf, but, as I understand it's a plugin that generate stuff.

So I'm gonna give you generic pointer hoping it will help.
I think you should either try to make 2 jar with different classifier from a single module, see https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/attached-jar.html
For example classifier proto2.4 and proto2.5
then you can add the classifier when you define the dependency to that module.

Other option I see is having 2 modules, the real one, you have now, and another one for 2.5
Generate a zip from the main one and the second module would be empty but have a dependency on the generated zip, unzip it and then compile with the plugin config for 2.5
Slower  at execution, a bit dirtier imho,  but can be needed  if for example you need more customization than just the version.

Comment: But then I'd have to remember to regenerate the zip file whenever something changes... Hmm...

Comment: well, it's simply run maven. use the assembly plugin to generate the zip file at the right phase

Comment: Yes, that works I admit...  It's a bit awkward, but it certainly does work.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got things to work more or less how I wanted.  I created a new module with JUST a pom file; that pom file refers to the proto files of the original module, but compiles them with the proto2.5 compiler and puts the result into its own directory.